# logging into fb from iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the below methods to login to fb through my app. It is successfully navigating to login page but printing an error as follows: 
**-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
** using swift 2.1.1 and facebook sdk 4.13.1

```
   let fbLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
  fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
    if (error == nil){
        let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
       if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil && fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
        {
            self.getFBUserData()

          //  fbLoginManager.logOut()
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

func getFBUserData(){

```
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, gender"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                print(result)

                let view = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("View") as! SignupViewController

               self.presentViewController(View, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
        })

}
```

}

```
Using 
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Also when I am redirecting to View, it goes to loginview and then going to redirected View.can anyone help me...

Comment: @can...nope it doesnt...I havent got a solution. that is why posted this.

Comment: Also...I can login to fb the app is not crashing or anything and I need to navigate to another viewcontroller after getting user info. So I dont think this could be a duplicate question.

Comment: Add fb<appID> in plist and in appdelegate method handle the url in canOpenUrl